# Rufus can't see my Kali .ISO

Tags: usb, bootable-media, rufus

I have an Iso file on my desktop. I go to select this in Rufus to make a bootable drive and it doesn't see it's existence. It saw this very iso when it was in my D USB drive but I had to move it because it can't be in the same location it's creating the drive in. So I move the file to the desktop (and I tried other folders too) and it's not showing up. Rufus is ghosting me. What's the solution?

[image: ISO disk image not showing]

Answer (score 3):

If one used admin privileges to execute Rufus, check the path and use the correct user's folders/files.

e.g.

C:\Users[user]\Downloads

Comment: Your answer is correct and is the fullest explanation; yet it is written with low clarity and detail. You should improve your answer by clarifying it. See my comment to the above answer from link as an example.

Comment: This solved the problem! I had to open Rufus with Admin privileges. So it wasn't showing me the ISO file in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my own problem. I still don't understand what happened. It couldn't see the file in Rufus, or in two other similar applications. Something was systemic/universal. Well I got it to recognize it by copying the file path and pasting it in. After that it could see it. It was there all along. I don't know why it behaved like that. It seems to be working. I'll get a chance to try boot it next month maybe when I have some spare time. That was a joke

Comment: Thanks for posting for solution.  Would you be willing to Edit the answer to make it shorter and more readable for a future user who stumbles on a similar issue?

Comment: Your workaround is related to the full explanation but does not grok it. The full explanation: Rufus navigates to directories such as Downloads, Documents, or Directories within %userprofile% of the account with which Rufus is launched. If you save your ISO in a non-privileged user account, then you launch Rufus as admin and authenticate with a separate account, then use Rufus uses the admin's Desktop, Documents, and Downloads. Manually browsing step-by-step through C:\ eliminates this problem by avoiding reliance on %userprofile%.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Rufus.

I solved the issue by placing the .iso file in a folder outside my windows User folder.  E.g. in a folder called ISO, on the c drive.

This suggests that .iso files located in the User folders it tried, i.e. Desktop or in the Downloads folder were not seen by Rufus.

Comment: This is strange, but it also worked for me for Ubuntu Boot. Thanks @artaxerxes