# Unable to boot Windows 10 USB created with Rufus

Tags: windows-10, liveusb, rufus

I've read this post
[I'm unable to boot my Windows 10 installer USB in UEFI mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/840578/im-unable-to-boot-my-windows-10-installer-usb-in-uefi-mode)

The Windows 10 .iso file was obtained via the Windows MediaCreationTool and selecting the ISO file option.

These are my Rufus settings

```
Standard Windows installation
GPT UEFI(non CSM)
FAT32
```

In my UEFI-BIOS I have disabled CSM.
Secure Boot is enabled.
and under Boot>OS Type I have tried both 'Windows UEFI Mode' and 'Other'

What happens is that when attempting to boot from the USB, I see the Windows logo briefly, then a black screen, then my PC reboots targeting the next item in my bootable media list.

Any troubleshooting steps appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried disabling Secure Boot?  Manufacturers can supply USB keys that boot with Secure Boot enabled, but I do not know if Rufus can emulate this. Try disabling Secure Boot.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the MediaCreationTool itself to create a bootable stick.

Is there any particular reason you need to use Rufus?

Comment: I second that.  Why on earth would you use the tool to download the ISO and not use the tool to create bootable media?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Unless doing something wrong only allowed my to create a MBR partitioned USB that wouldn't recognize the GPT partition map on the target drive.