# Creating NTFS bootable USB drive

Tags: boot, usb, ntfs, iso-image, windows-server

I am trying to create bootable USB drive from MSDN Windows Server 2016 ISO file but one of the files in the image named install.wim is 4.38 GB in size so FAT32 drive will not work nor can I create a bootable DVD drive because size of the image is 5.26 GB.

When I create the drive using Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool the drive remains NTFS but it is not bootable.
When I use UltraISO it always formats the drive as FAT32 and is bootable but install fails because intall.wim file is invalid.

What is the solution to this problem? Is there a tool that will create bootable NTFS USB drive I can use to install Windows Server?

Comment: @n8te Thanks, I'll take a look at RUFUS, just found some powershell script that is supposed to take care of this problem by splitting install.wim. If that doesn't work I'll try RUFUS next...

Comment: The script didn't work and the problem with RUFUS is that when I choose exFAT the option  'Create a bootable disk using:' which allows you to select ISO file is no longer available. It's only available when you choose FAT32 or NTFS. WIth FAT32 install.wim will not be valid and with NTFS it will not boot.

Comment: Try NTFS in RUFUS then. I hadn't attempted an NTFS bootable flash yet but I'm creating one right now just for curiosity's sake.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now as well, there are three options for "Partition scheme and target system type" drop down and I'm first trying with "MBR partition scheme for UEFI".

Comment: None of the three options worked for me, when the file system is NTFS it will not boot but I found this answer from user Akeo who is apparently the author of RUFUS https://superuser.com/a/896667/66496 stating choosing "GPT partition scheme for UEFI computers and also settting the file system to NTFS" in RUFUS will allow booting from NTFS.  That did not work for me. The machine is DELL Precision T5500 with the latest BIOS A16...

Comment: Looks like your PC is a bit older. It's running a legacy BIOS instead of UEFI. I'm out of suggestions. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Did the simple thing and bought a dual layer DVD, burned the image and installed from there.

Microsoft has a [tutorial](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825096.aspx) on how to split the large wim files using [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-windows-mdt/get-started-with-the-microsoft-deployment-toolkit) that is totally convoluted...